# metatrader 4 on raspberry pi4

Tags: pi-4

I have a raspberry pi 4 with Raspbian and I have installed PlayOnLinux to run metatrader 4 but I don't get it to work. when I run playonlinux i get Error in POL_Wine, . what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what distro you're using, since the playonlinux [Download Page](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html) only seems to support metatrader on Jessie or Stretch. Might be problematic on Buster.

My guess is the 'Error in POL_Wine' means the PlayOnLinux installation process was damaged or corrupted. Also, the MetaTrader site suggest using Wine on Ubuntu, and even that combo may still have issues.  [METATRADER 4 ON LINUX](https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform/help/userguide/install_linux)